# Why is Lua loops slow?

Tags: performance, lua

Lua is said to be a fast scripting language. But when I tested looping e.g.:

```
a = 0
while a < 1000000000 do
    a = a + 1
end
```

It takes a lot of time (over 1 minute). Is it because Lua needs to copy and paste loop's content, and then evaluate?

I know that when evaluating you need to pop() items away from stack.

I tested this "speed-test" on Ruby too and it did the loop in about 20s.

EDIT:
Why is this so much faster on local variables? (~16 seconds to do same iteration but on local variable inside function)

Comment: How slow is slow? What execution times are you getting?

Comment: Over one minute. Please don't down vote right away. Tell me what's wrong with my question first please.

Comment: Well first of all Lua doesn't copy-paste it lol

Comment: One likely reason is that lua variables are *variants*, they can be any type, any time, which means that your statement `a = a + 1` first has to figure out *which* `+` operator to use and whether to convert any of the operands. Same with `a < 10000....` which has to figure out which `<` operator to use and again whether any of the operands has to be converted. A `for` loop, on the other hand, which takes *a lot* less time to execute probably runs more native code that deals with integer values implicitly and thus doesn't have as much overhead.

Comment: 3 times slower is not a reason to start worrying about slowness :)  Try LuaJIT, it will beat Ruby in this benchmark.

Comment: Yes, variables are "variants". But you still use a pointer to it right? Do Lua have to search for the variable (in a map or similar) 'a' in every loop?

Comment: I think Ruby and LuaJIT in this case are about equal speeds.

Answer (score 6):

Try the code below. It compares while vs for loops and globals vs local variables.

I get these numbers (with Lua 5.1.4,  but they are similar for 5.3.2), which tell you the cost of using global variables in a loop:

```
WG  9.16    100
WL  1.96    467
FG  4.93    186
FL  1.18    776
```

Of course, these costs get diluted if you do real work inside the loop.

Here is the code:

```
local N=1e8

t0=os.clock()
a = 0
while a < N do
    a = a + 1
end
t1=os.clock()-t0
print("WG",t1,math.floor(t1/t1*100+0.5))

t0=os.clock()
local a = 0
while a < N do
    a = a + 1
end
t2=os.clock()-t0
print("WL",t2,math.floor(t1/t2*100+0.5))

t0=os.clock()
b = 0
for i=1,N do
    b = b + 1
end
t3=os.clock()-t0
print("FG",t3,math.floor(t1/t3*100+0.5))

t0=os.clock()
local b = 0
for i=1,N do
    b = b + 1
end
t4=os.clock()-t0
print("FL",t4,math.floor(t1/t4*100+0.5))
```

Comment: What's the second number representing?

Comment: Also, are you using LuaJIT? Took me about three minutes to finish on vanilla Lua.

Comment: @user6245072 Second number is speed difference in %% relative to first slowest loop. And that's not LuaJIT. I ran that sample on vanilla lua 5.1.5 and got even smaller times, probably because of faster cpu. LuaJIT would give x10 times smaller numbers, making even first loop finish in 180ms to me. But actual importance of that test is to show how different is global and local variables in terms of access speed.

Comment: You must go a really really fast computer :I

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is inefficient and unpractical.

You're doing *one billion iterations*. That's not exactly "light".

Not to mention you're using a `while` loop to substitute a numeric `for` loop.

Comment: And yet this "not exactly light" operation takes on the order of 300 milliseconds to run in C# but takes 1m14s on the same computer in lua. There *is* significant overhead here :)

Comment: A `for` loop instead takes 6-7 seconds.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen C# is a compiled statically-typed language, you cannot even compare that. These are scripting languages, and on Python it took more than 2.5 minutes for me even.

Comment: I know, it was stated as sort of a baseline comparison, not a reflection on the actual *speed* of lua. I think the important part here is to know the language and know that `for` *for this particular scenario* is going to have a lot less overhead.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oh alright, I misunderstood you then

Comment: This is not inefficient. This is a benchmark. Try putting a local variable in a function and do the same iteration and you'll notice the huge difference.

Comment: @lucas That case literally only applies if it's specifically for a benchmark. But in practical code, so many iterations to accomplish a task WOULD be inefficient.